# Data table not displaying anything and Plot Model only displays a graph frame with nothing in it in shinyapp

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot, shinyapps

The data table not displaying anything and Plot Model only displays a graph frame with nothing in it in shinyapp. How do I just make the table to show all the data that I have in the Seattle Portage Bay CSV? I think the scatter plot graph doesn't know where my data is coming from and I don't know how to fix it.

Somehow my total precipitation and minimum temp map don't work now too.

```
# shape <- st_read("tl_2016_53_cousub.shp")
# sta <- read_csv("NOAA_SeattlePortageBay.csv") %>% #weather station
#   mutate(lon = Longitude, lat = Latitude) %>%
#   st_as_sf(coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), crs=4326) %>%
#   st_join(shape)

trend_data <- read_csv("NOAA_SeattlePortageBay.csv")

y <- trend_data %>%
  sample_n(0) %>%       
  select("Year", "Total Liquid Content", "Extreme Max Precip", "Annual Mean Temp", "Mean Max Temp", "Mean Min Temp") 


ui <- fluidPage(title = "Seattle, Washington 40 Years Climate",
                navlistPanel(
                  tabPanel(title = "Introduction",
                           leafletOutput("map"),
                           textOutput("dis")),

                  tabPanel(title = "Climate Graphs",
                           plotOutput("plot1"),
                           # plotOutput("plot2"),
                           plotOutput("plot3"),
                           plotOutput("plot4"),
                           plotOutput("plot5")),

                  tabPanel(title = "Data Table",
                           tableOutput("table")),

                  tabPanel(title = "Plot Model",
                           plotOutput("scatterplot"),
                           varSelectInput("yvar", "Y Variable:", data=y, selected="Total Liquid Content"))
                )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output$map <- renderLeaflet({   #doesn't work so I use another route
  #   leaflet(data = sta) %>%
  #     addTiles() %>%
  #     addMarkers(~lon, ~lat, label = ~Name)
  #     output$dis <- renderText("Seattle is a city located in the State of Washington.
  #                            Seattle Portage Bay Weather Station by NOAA.")

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaf <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addMarkers(lng=-122.3, lat= 47.65,
                 popup="Seattle Portage Bay, WA, USA, GHCND:USW00024281")
  })

  output$dis <- renderText("Seattle Portage Bay Weather Station by NOAA.\n
                           Elevation: 5.8m \n
                           Period of Record: January 1, 1894 to January 1, 1997")

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({                         
    ggplot(trend_data) +                              
      geom_point(aes(Year, trend_data$`Total Liquid Content`),
                 size = 3, color = "dark blue") +
      geom_smooth(aes(Year, trend_data$`Total Liquid Content`), size = 1, color = "black", method = "lm") +
      labs(title = "Total Precipitation",
           x = "Year", y = "Precipitation in Inches") +
      theme(text= element_text(size=15,  family="Arial"), 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(15, 55) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1940, to = 2000, by = 5))
  })

  # output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  #   ggplot(trend_data) +
  #     geom_point(aes(Year, trend_data$`Extreme Max Precip`),
  #                size = 3, color = "red") +
  #     geom_smooth(aes(Year, trend_data$`Extreme Max Precip`), size = 1, color = "black", method = "lm") +
  #     labs(title = "Extreme Max Precipitation",
  #          x = "Year", y = "Precipitation in Inches") +
  #     theme(text= element_text(size=15,  family="Arial"),
  #           plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(15, 55) +
  #     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1940, to = 2000, by = 5))
  # })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(trend_data) + 
      geom_point(aes(Year, trend_data$`Annual Mean Temp`), 
                 size = 3, color = "brown") + 
      geom_smooth(aes(Year, trend_data$`Annual Mean Temp`), size = 1, color = "black", method = "lm") + 
      labs(title = "Average Temperature",
           x = "Year", y = "Temperature in Fahrenheit") +
      theme(text= element_text(size=15,  family="Arial"), 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(50, 56) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1940, to = 2000, by = 5))
  })

  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(trend_data) + 
      geom_point(aes(Year, trend_data$`Mean Max Temp`), 
                 size = 3, color = "red") + 
      geom_smooth(aes(Year, trend_data$`Mean Max Temp`), size = 1, color = "black", method = "lm") +
      labs(title = "Average Maximum Temperature",
           x = "Year", y = "Temperature in Fahrenheit") +
      theme(text= element_text(size=15,  family="Arial"), 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(57, 64) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1940, to = 2000, by = 5))
  })

  output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(trend_data) + 
      geom_point(aes(Year, trend_data$`Mean Min Temp`), 
                 size = 3, color = "light blue") + 
      geom_smooth(aes(Year, trend_data$`Mean Min Temp`), size = 1, color = "black", method = "lm") + 
      labs(title = "Average Minimum Temperature",
           x = "Year", y = "Temperature in Fahrenheit") +
      theme(text= element_text(size=15,  family="Arial"), 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(43, 50) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1940, to = 2000, by = 5))
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(trend_data)

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = y) +              #can't find function y
      geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = !!input$yvar)) +
      geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = !!input$yvar), method="lm")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Shelly.. I am not familiar with your data, but why did you do y <- trend_data %>%
  sample_n(0), doesn't this return you an empty data frame?

Answer (score 1):

you use tableOutput("table") on ui side, while on the server side you use renderDataTable(trend_data), they are not matched so no table will be displayed

while for the data itself, you use this function

```
y <- trend_data %>%
  sample_n(0) %>%       
  select("Year", "Total Liquid Content", "Extreme Max Precip", "Annual Mean Temp", "Mean Max Temp", "Mean Min Temp")
```

the sample_n(0) will return 0 rows, essentially you have no data and would not display anything